# How to register a user using only javascript/ajax or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to register users using only javascript,ajax or jquery, i need to save the information of the users somewhere where i can get it even after the browser is closed,and the new information can't overwrite the old one.
I already tried saving into a xml file or txt file, but without success.

Comment: LocalStorage or Cookies?

Comment: will it be pratical using that even with 10 or more users?

Comment: Or you can use a database...

Comment: i can't use databases or php,i'm not allowed to

Comment: Well then the only solution might be to save it to a file.

Comment: Can i save the users in local storage, in a variable,separated by spaces or something,and then split the variable into an array to check the username and such?

Comment: You can save it in localStorage, but I'm not sure that you could see it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check these out, one of it might help

http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/ - Indexed DB

http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/ - Web Sql
http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/ - localStorage

You can as well try out a JavaScript Database here
http://www.taffydb.com/ still trying it out myself, hope this helps.